# how to find EMI and how to find Principal Amount if EMI is given?

Tags: sas

I have two Questions 2 ask:-

(1).if principleamount =10,000 , Interest=4% abd Term=5Yrs(60 Months) then how to find EMI through PMT function or is there any function to find?????

(2) if I have EMI=350,Term=5yrs(60 Months) and Interest=4% then how to find Principal Amount????

5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took some searching to learn that EMI is "Equated Monthly Installments", so if that means what I think it does, you can use the `MORT` function, [documented here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/63354/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1lu2y2jwy3twmn1mns17ix45c6o.htm).

For Q1:

```
data _null_;
   principal = 10000;
   interest = .04/12; /* Monthly rate */
   term = 60;
   payment = .;

   payment = mort(principal, payment , interest, term);
   put payment=;
run;
```

For Q2:

```
data _null_;
   principal = .;
   interest = .04/12; /* Monthly rate */
   term = 60;
   payment = 350;

   principal = mort(principal, payment, interest, term);
   put principal=;
run;
```

Notice that the `MORT` function returns whichever value is missing.